# Generate all possible combinations between two columns and an indicator to show if that combination exists in the source table

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am completely lost at a particular stage on doing a transformation.

I am planning to achieve it either by using SQL or pyspark.

My input format is.

```
id  name
1   A
1   C
1   E
2   A
2   B
2   C
2   E
2   F
3   A
3   E
3   D
```

Could you please help me getting this output format.

```
id name rating
1  A    1
1  B    0
1  C    1
1  D    0
1  E    1
1  F    0
2  A    1
2  B    1
2  C    1
2  D    0
2  E    1
2  F    1
3  A    1
3  B    0
3  C    0
3  D    1
3  E    1
3  F    0
```

As the sql query is taking forever just want to see if I can achieve the same using pyspark for feeding the data set into an ALS.

In other words, how do I generate all possible combinations between id and name and if the combination exists with in table set the rating to 1 otherwise 0?

Comment: with other words generate all possible combinations between id and name.. if the combination exists with in table the rating is 1 otherwise 0?

Comment: @RaymondNijland yes that is correct.

Comment: Ok.. Check mine answer

Comment: *"As the sql query is taking forever"* i saw a answer update and i did a review  Yes when you use a CROSS JOINing and the table has alot off records it will be slow yes.. You need to make two querys (the two distinct) store then in the list and use something like Python's [itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) and don't forgot the make indexes on the column id and name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> With other words generate all possible combinations between id and
>   name.. if the combination exists with in table the rating is 1
>   otherwise 0?

You need to use two deriverd tables in combination with a `CROSS JOIN` to get every id and name combination possible.

**Query**

```
SELECT 
 *
FROM ( 

 SELECT 
   *
  FROM (
    SELECT
      DISTINCT
       id
    FROM
      Table1    
  ) AS distinct_id
  CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT 
      DISTINCT 
        name
    FROM 
    Table1 
  ) AS distinct_name
) AS table_combination

 ORDER BY 
    id ASC
  , name ASC
```

**Result**

```
| id | name |
|----|------|
|  1 |    A |
|  1 |    B |
|  1 |    C |
|  1 |    D |
|  1 |    E |
|  1 |    F |
|  2 |    A |
|  2 |    B |
|  2 |    C |
|  2 |    D |
|  2 |    E |
|  2 |    F |
|  3 |    A |
|  3 |    B |
|  3 |    C |
|  3 |    D |
|  3 |    E |
|  3 |    F |
```

see demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ba5f17/17

Now we can use `LEFT JOIN` in combination with `CASE WHEN column IS NULL ... END` to check if the combination exists within the current table or if the combination is generated.

**Query**

```
SELECT
   Table_combination.id
 , Table_combination.name
 , (
     CASE 
      WHEN Table1.id IS NULL
      THEN 0
      ELSE 1
     END
   ) AS rating
FROM ( 

  SELECT 
   *
  FROM (
    SELECT
      DISTINCT
       id
    FROM
      Table1    
  ) AS distinct_id
  CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT 
      DISTINCT 
        name
    FROM 
    Table1 
  ) AS distinct_name
) AS Table_combination

LEFT JOIN 
 Table1
ON
   Table_combination.id = Table1.id
 AND
   Table_combination.name = Table1.name

ORDER BY 
   Table_combination.id ASC
 , Table_combination.name ASC
```

**Result**

```
| id | name | rating |
|----|------|--------|
|  1 |    A |      1 |
|  1 |    B |      0 |
|  1 |    C |      1 |
|  1 |    D |      0 |
|  1 |    E |      1 |
|  1 |    F |      0 |
|  2 |    A |      1 |
|  2 |    B |      1 |
|  2 |    C |      1 |
|  2 |    D |      0 |
|  2 |    E |      1 |
|  2 |    F |      1 |
|  3 |    A |      1 |
|  3 |    B |      0 |
|  3 |    C |      0 |
|  3 |    D |      1 |
|  3 |    E |      1 |
|  3 |    F |      0 |
```

see demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ba5f17/13

Answer (score 0):

I made a function based off of Raymond Nijlands answer:

```
def expand_grid(df, df_name, col_a, col_b, col_c):
    df.createOrReplaceTempView(df_name)
    expand_sql = f"""
        SELECT
            expanded.{col_a},
            expanded.{col_b},
            CASE
                WHEN {df_name}.{col_c} IS NULL THEN 0
                ELSE {df_name}.{col_c}
            END AS {col_c}
        FROM ( 
            SELECT *
            FROM (
                SELECT DISTINCT {col_a}
                FROM {df_name}    
            ) AS {col_a}s
            CROSS JOIN (
                SELECT DISTINCT {col_b}
                FROM {df_name}
            ) AS {col_b}s
        ) AS expanded
        LEFT JOIN {df_name}
        ON expanded.{col_a} = {df_name}.{col_a}
        AND expanded.{col_b} = {df_name}.{col_b}
    """
    print(expand_sql)
    result = spark.sql(expand_sql)
    return result
```

Usage in context of this question:

```
expand_grid(df=df, df_name="df_name", col_a="id", col_b="name", col_c="rating")
```